# Failure to get magnetic declination

Tags: c++, linux, linker-errors

I am trying to run a code in order to get the value of magnetic declination with the help of data from the world magnetic model which is being accessed by the GeographicLib library.
But, compilation is failing due to multiple `"undefined reference to"` errors.

Background:

1. The geographic library has been extracted to the default location of `/usr/local`
2. IDE used to run the code is Geany
3. operating on raspberry pi 4, Raspbian booted
4. commands tried to run via bash terminal =

```
(a) g++ work_cpp.cpp -o p 
(b) g++ work_cpp.cpp wmm.h -o p
```

5. tried to build via the IDE itself =

```
 g++ -Wall -o "work_cpp" "work_cpp.cpp" (in directory: /home/pi/Desktop/picodes)
```

I have tried a few things but they have failed to work so far:

1. sudo copied the sbin and include files of the GeographicLib from `/usr/local` to  `/usr/bin`
2. sudo copied `/usr/include` header files to the library's location ie

```
/usr/local/include/GeographicLib
```

As a neophyte, I am being overwhelmed by these undefined errors, and am desperate to get answers and my code running.

---

Code for the same is as follows:

work_cpp.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "wmm.h"

int main(){
    std::cout<<"starting...\n\r"<<std::endl;
    wmm * magnetic_model = new wmm();
    std::cout<<"\033[2J\033[?25l"<<std::endl;
    while(1){
        magnetic_model->update(19.07283,72.88261,10);
        std::cout<<"\033[0;0H"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Declination: %2.3f\n\r"<<magnetic_model->declination()<<std::endl;
        }
        delete magnetic_model;
    return 0;}
```

wmm.h

```
#ifndef __WMM_H__
#define __WMM_H__
#include <GeographicLib/MagneticModel.hpp>
using namespace GeographicLib;
class wmm
{
private:
    double magnetic_declination;
    double magnetic_inclination;
    double field_strength;

public:
    double declination();
    double inclination();
    double strength();
    void update(float lat, float lon, float alt);
};
#endif
void wmm::update(float lat, float lon, float alt)
{
    double Bx, By, Bz, H;
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    tm* timePtr = localtime(&t);
    MagneticModel mag("emm2015");
    mag(timePtr->tm_year + 1900, lat, lon, alt, Bx, By, Bz);
    MagneticModel::FieldComponents(Bx, By, Bz, H, field_strength, magnetic_declination, magnetic_inclination);
}
```

---

Error message:

```
g++ -Wall -o "work_cpp" "work_cpp.cpp" (in directory: /home/pi/Desktop/picodes)
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccEL2G3m.o: in function `wmm::update(float, float, float)':
work_cpp.cpp:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `GeographicLib::Geocentric::WGS84()'
/usr/bin/ld: work_cpp.cpp:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `GeographicLib::MagneticModel::MagneticModel(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, GeographicLib::Geocentric const&, int, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccEL2G3m.o: in function `main':
work_cpp.cpp:(.text+0x288): undefined reference to `wmm::declination()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccEL2G3m.o: in function `GeographicLib::MagneticModel::operator()(double, double, double, double, double&, double&, double&) const':
work_cpp.cpp:(.text._ZNK13GeographicLib13MagneticModelclEddddRdS1_S1_[_ZNK13GeographicLib13MagneticModelclEddddRdS1_S1_]+0x6c): undefined reference to `GeographicLib::MagneticModel::Field(double, double, double, double, bool, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&) const'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccEL2G3m.o: in function `GeographicLib::MagneticModel::FieldComponents(double, double, double, double&, double&, double&, double&)':
work_cpp.cpp:(.text._ZN13GeographicLib13MagneticModel15FieldComponentsEdddRdS1_S1_S1_[_ZN13GeographicLib13MagneticModel15FieldComponentsEdddRdS1_S1_S1_]+0x70): undefined reference to `GeographicLib::MagneticModel::FieldComponents(double, double, double, double, double, double, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Compilation failed.
```

Comment: Not familiar with that library, but `undefined reference` means linker did not found the functions, are you sure you did not forget to link the library? I do not see any linking in the posted build commands.

Comment: When you say "the geographic library", can you specify which one? You need to **link** with a .so or .a file that contains the actual code for the library.

Comment: wmm.h is the header file needed to compile. To link your program you need to add the corresponding library which will be named something like libwmm.so. For example `-L /usr/local/lib -l wmm`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you *actually* meant a library called ["GeographicLib"](https://github.com/sotex/geographiclib), you forgot to *link* with that library.

Change your compilation command to:

```
g++ -Wall -o "work_cpp" "work_cpp.cpp" -L/usr/local/lib -lGeographic
```

This will tell the compiler to look for libGeographic.so (or libGeographic.a if you want to link statically) in both the normal paths and /usr/local/lib.

Regarding the errors about `wmm::declination()` and `wmm::inclination()`: you need to define these methods yourself. I don't know your use case, but it could be as simple as defining directly in your class definition (in your header file):

```
double declination() { return magnetic_declination; }
```

A more involved definition should go in your .cpp file:

```
double wmm::declination() { return magnetic_declination; }
```

Comment: Okay so turns out I had not linked the library properly, which was very well pointed out in the comments. I ran the command with proper linking as suggested. This did help me reduce significant amount of errors, except one. 
the final error message:

g++ -Wall -o "work_cpp" "work_cpp.cpp" -L/usr/local/lib -lGeographic
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc5ZABH1.o: in function `main':
work_cpp.cpp:(.text+0x288): undefined reference to `wmm::declination()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I amended my answer for that: _you_ need to define that function.

Comment: oh okay got it, will look into it right away ... Thanks !

Comment: lovely it did compile successfully